# Are PNR numbers referred to in the boarding pass?

Tags: tickets

My question is about the booking references, that I would like to know whether the PNR no. will be referred somewhere in the Boarding pass?

Comment: Yes it is usually printed on the boarding pass as well. What does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, boarding pass usually has PNR on it, as I have found from a brief image search.

It is usually marked as such, but otherwise you can try and locate it - short-ish, mainly or exclusively consists of letters in caps.